# How i pass data from one controller to another controller in node express app?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get data from signup controller in my express app to check the otp but I can't get the data. What should the function to get data from one controller to another controller in express node application.

Comment: Add some code to better understand the problem

Comment: Please provide some code you have.